# Brand New to Coding = Python [Two Days In]

Tags: python

Why doesn't this work?

I wanted to create a loop that would change the value of an array element, and keep track of the print count.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = 1

while y < 6:
    print("Done", y)
    y += 1
while y > 4:
    x [4] = 69
print(x [4])
```

Comment: If you enter your second `while` loop (your code will, as it is written), you'll never break out.   Consider changing your loop condition or modifying `y` inside the second loop.  But you'd probably be better off finding a online "intro to python"-type tutorial that you can follow along with.

Comment: This has too many errors in a snippet. This is normal for a beginner! but you need to practice isolating errors both to ask StackOverflow questions and because that's how *you'll* fix them.  I recommend running this line by line in an interactive shell, e.g. IPython, and examining the values of each variable as you go.

Comment: Perhaps you were expecting the `while` loops to execute concurrently. The first one will repeat until y == 6. Then the second one starts (and runs forever). Can you show the output you are expecting?

Comment: Avoid asking questions of the form 'why doesn't this work?'. Include in your question details of attempts you have made to solve the problem. Finally, be more specific when explaining your problem (include error messages, expected output, &c.)

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = 1

while y < 6:
    print("Done", y)
    y += 1

# now y becomes 6

while y > 4: #Always True because Y is always 6
    x [4] = 69
```

So now it is infinite loop. So you need to modify the second loop block to:

```
while y > 4:
    x [4] = 69
    y -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `while` loop proceeds until `y` is 6, incrementing it by one each time -- so far so good.

Then, the second `while` loop continues as long as `y > 4` -- and it **doesn't** change `y`, so `y` remains to the value 6, and the second loop continues repeating forever...

Comment: So, add `y -= 1` to the second loop if you want to keep the structure